# How can I change the radius of a particular circle when clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have already asked a question that helped me figure out how to change the radius of a circle when clicking on the circle.

```
<g id="bubble-nodes">
    <rect id="bubble-background"></rect>
    <a class="class="bubble-node">
        <circle r="65"></circle>
    </a>
    ....
</g>

var circle = d3
.selectAll('circle')
.on('click', function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("r", 85);
});
```

Now, I'm asking how I can change the radius of a particular circle when clicking on a button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="resizeParticularCircle('circle_12')">Click Me</button>

<g id="bubble-nodes">
    <rect id="bubble-background"></rect>
    <a class="class="bubble-node">
        <circle r="65" id="circle_12"></circle>
    </a>
    ....
</g>

var resizeParticularCircle = function (id) {
    // nothing I have tried works
    $('#circle_12').attr('r', '85'); // nope
}
```

In pure javascript/jquery I would probably place an `id` on each circle and reference that to alter another element. But how can I do the same thing in D3?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jxof57ac/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `id` attribute as follows:

```
circle.attr('id', function(d, i){ return 'circle_' + i;});
```

Or set the class:

```
circle.attr('class', function(d, i){ 
   if(i === 12){
     return 'specialCircle';} else {
     return 'normalCircle';}
});
```